# Раcпарсить число

Tags: javascript, html, json

Переменные а и b содержат строки формата `(1,2)`. Нужно распарсить строку после знака и привести к числу, чтоб получилось, к примеру, `1 2 1 3`, и запихнуть эти числа либо в 4 разные переменные, либо в массив.

Распарсить нужно после запятой (то есть была строка `1,2` стало число `1` и число `2`, так же и со второй переменной).

Конкретизирую: при первом клике переменная 1 берет id элемента, при втором клике переменная 2 берет id другого элемента и дальше передает эти переменные в качестве аргумента в функцию. На этом этапе и возникает ошибка. Вот я и подумал, что скорее всего проблема в этом.

Подскажите как такое реализовать?

Comment: Опишите что именно нужно сделать, частности как распарсить, после какого знака и так далее. В процессе сами поймете что делать, я думаю.

Comment: Конкретизируйте задачу: приведите свой код, с указанием на то, что конкретно не работает.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов , исправил описание

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev добавил пример кода

Comment: А где в вашем коде что-то, что должно парсить эти строки?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev , его нет потому, что я не знаю как это сделать , раншен с этим не сталкивался, поэтому и оставил этот вопрос тут.

Comment: Знал бы как разпарсить то не спрашивал бы тут )))

Comment: Тогда зачем вы приводите код, который не имеет отношения к вопросу?

Comment: ... и почему не можете его как следует оформить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделить строку на массив легко с помощью [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
Если нужно преобразовать именно в число, то есть изменить тип со strin на number . то это делается с помощью [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Примеры настолько простые что код писать думаю смысла нету.